# Copying a Test Plan to Different Projects

Tags: azure-devops

I'm considering setting up a Project in Azure DevOps as Master Regression Test, which will have test plans, suites, test cases, steps, etc. I'd like to be able to copy the test plans into other projects during regression testing.

Answer (score 1):

1.You can create a query to query the test plans you need to migrate.

[image]

2.Click "...", "move to team project" option will appear, click it

[image]

3.Choose Destination project to move test plan

[image]

For details guide , you can also refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items?view=azure-devops#move-a-work-item-to-another-project).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to be able to copy the test plans into other projects during
>   regression testing.

You can achieve this with the plugin: [Test Case Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.TestCaseExplorer). After install this plugin, please back to your org. And then open **test case**-> **Pivot by Test plan**, you will see a icon which means Copy. Click that, and specified the target project you want to clone to:

[image]

And also, here has another way to copy the test plan: [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test%20plan%20clone/clone%20test%20plan?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/CloneOperation?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

Specified the **destination project** in request body, here is my sample request body:

```
{"destinationTestPlan":
  {
    "name":"{new test plan name}",
    "project":
    {
        "Name":"destination project name"}
    },
    "options":
    {
    "cloneRequirements":false,
    "copyAllSuites":true,
    "copyAncestorHierarchy":true,
    "overrideParameters":
    {
        "System.AreaPath":"{Areapath name}",
        "System.IterationPath":"{Iteration name}"
    },
    "destinationWorkItemType":"{name of the workitem type of the clone}",
    "relatedLinkComment":"Comment"
    },
    "suiteIds":[]
}
```

For more details about the request body, you can check the doc: [Test Plan Clone - Clone Test Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test%20plan%20clone/clone%20test%20plan?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#destinationtestplancloneparams)